# Ruby 2.3.3 The Well Grounded Rubyist - undefined method `balance' for 25:Fixnum

Tags: ruby, fixnum

I'm currently going through "The Well Grounded Rubyist 2nd Edition"
I'm on page 196 and have been given the following code

```
class Account
  attr_accessor :balance

  def initialize(amount=0)
    self.balance = amount
  end

  def +(x)
    self.balance += x
  end

  def -(x)
    self.balance -= x
  end

  def to_s
    balance.to_s
  end

end
```

I've used this in and irb session, like so

```
2.3.3 :001 > require './account.rb'
 => true
2.3.3 :002 > acc = Account.new(20)
 => #<Account:0x007fccb1834ef8 @balance=20>
2.3.3 :003 > balance
NameError: undefined local variable or method `balance' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/BartJudge/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.3 :004 > acc.balance
 => 20
2.3.3 :005 > acc+=5
 => 25
2.3.3 :006 > acc.balance
NoMethodError: undefined method `balance' for 25:Fixnum
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/BartJudge/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.3 :007 > acc -= 5
 => 20
2.3.3 :008 > acc.balance
NoMethodError: undefined method `balance' for 20:Fixnum
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/BartJudge/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.3 :009 >
```

Line 4 works the way I expected it work `acc.balance`
However, when I use it again in line 8, i get the following error `` undefined method `balance' for 20:Fixnum ``

When I do the following, it works consistently as I expect.

```
 => true
2.3.3 :002 > acc = Account.new(20)
 => #<Account:0x007f82d1834f18 @balance=20>
2.3.3 :003 > acc.balance
 => 20
2.3.3 :004 > acc.balance
 => 20
2.3.3 :005 > acc.+ (5)
 => 25
2.3.3 :006 > acc.balance
 => 25
2.3.3 :007 > acc.-(10)
 => 15
2.3.3 :008 > acc.balance
 => 15
2.3.3 :009 >
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with how the methods are being called, but I can't find anything to explain it.
Is anyone able to shed some light on the disparity of the results, and why FIXNUM is getting involved.
I thought @balance would be an INTEGER.

TIA.

Comment: `acc + 5` is short for `acc.+(5)`

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` and `-=` assignment operators actually reassign the variable. `acc += 1` actually just a shorthand for `acc = acc + 1`.

> And why FIXNUM is getting involved. I thought @balance would be an INTEGER.

Prior to Ruby 2.4 there where two classes - Fixnum and Bignum that represent integers of different sizes.

Ruby 2.4 replaced them with a [unified Integer class](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/18/ruby-2-4-unifies-fixnum-and-bignum-into-integer.html).

Comment: Technically speaking, there was always only an `Integer` class in Ruby, with the proviso that implementations were allowed to have implementation-specific subclasses. However, the programmer was not allowed to rely on them being there.

Comment: `Fixnum` / `Bignum` exist(s/ed) in MRI, YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, and IronRuby, I believe, but e.g. MacRuby had `NSInteger` instead, if I remember correctly, and MagLev used the underlying Smalltalk VM's number representation. Personally, I always considered exposing this performance optimization a mistake. Compare with *flonums* in YARV, or the small string and small object optimizations in various Implementations that are completely transparent to the programmer.

Comment: For example, some implementations optimize objects with a small number of instance variables by storing the instance variables inside the object header at fixed offsets instead of in an instance variable table. However, it would be really strange to see a `SmallObject` and `BigObject` subclass of `Object` and objects magically moving between them … yet that is *exactly* what integral numbers do in older versions of YARV.

Comment: YARV still performs the exact same optimization than before, it just doesn't expose it any more. This optimization is well-known and has been used by Smalltalks and Lisps for decades, MRI was just "different" in that it exposed it, and naturally, almost all other implementations followed it, since "MRI was the spec".

Comment: The depth of your knowledge here is pretty amazing. I've barely even stepped outside of MRI. Hopefully we got it right by now though.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `balance` alone will raise `NameError` because it's trying to call an object on main which has not been defined.  You 'll get the same error if you just call random words like `foo` or `bar`.  Methods must be called on an object.

Max's answer explains part of the problem.  However I would suggest you define your class like this to avoid the bug.

```
class Account
  attr_accessor :balance

  def initialize(amount=0)
    @balance = amount
  end

  def add(x)
    @balance += x
  end

  def subtract(x)
    @balance -= x
  end

  def to_s
    @balance.to_s
  end

end
```

Comment: I agree, but I suspect that the the point of the example was to explain overriding operators.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm just confused why calling the method with a dot, doesn't result in the '''undefined method `balance' ''' but when I call a method without a dot it does. I am using the '''acc.balance ''' so I'm not sure what you mean when you say I'm calling the method on main. I am always calling methods on the instance of the Account class.

Comment: @Bart_Judge Ruby to simplify this, run an irb console `irb` and then just typen `self` and enter. you will get `=>main`. Ruby looks to see if the object being called is defined. It tries to find it in the current scope.  The error is telling you that `balance` is not defined on that scope `main`.  When you call `obj.method` it will try to called `method` on `obj`.  But if not, it will look for the next possible scope.

Comment: @lacostenycoder So, when I'm doing ```acc+=5``` Ruby thinks I'm trying to call it on main? But then, how is it able to add 5 to 20 to get 25? ```2.3.3 :004 > acc.balance
 => 20
2.3.3 :005 > acc+=5
 => 25
2.3.3 :006 > acc.balance
NoMethodError: undefined method `balance' for 25:Fixnum```